# VBScript Having Trouble with getElementsbyTagName

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, web-applications, vbscript

I am trying to find an anchor tag in the DOM by searching the inner text and then simulate a click on the link that has inner text that matches a particular string of text. I have tried the following

```
Option Explicit

Dim objIE : Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "http://myURL"
objIE.Visible = True

WScript.Sleep 10000

' loop through links
Dim anchor
For Each anchor in objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
  ' check text for link
  If InStr(UCase(anchor.innerText), "DOCUMENT LIST") > 0 Then
    ' navigate to the first match and exit the for...next loop
    anchor.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

This script opens up internet explorer to the correct page, but I get an error at

```
For Each anchor in objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

that says

```
The interface is unknown
```

I feel that the problem has something to do with the fact that **once the web application opens up, the URL changes**, though the display remains the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `objIE.document.location.href.getElementsByTagName("a")` or `objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")`? Cus the first one looks very wrong

Comment: The second one. I meant to edit that part. Sorry.